# Synapse SQL: Error in Inserting url link into Synapse Table

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I am facing issues while INSERTing a URL into Synapse Table.

```
DECLARE @today datetime;
SET @today = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

INSERT INTO table_url([APITag]
       ,[AuthAPIUrl]
       ,[DataFetchUrl]
       ,[CreatedOn]
       ,[CreatedBy])
VALUES
     ('Indent',
      'https://beta-url.<url_name>.com',
      'https://beta-url.<url_name>.com',
      @today,
      'Abcd')
```

But the above statement is giving error:

> Msg 104455, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to
> connect to a different Database.
> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Parse error at line: 11, column: 12: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Don't know what I am missing here. Is there any way to convert the URL into string?

Comment: As the error states: `USE statement is not supported` You cannot use `USE dbname`

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing in my environment, I have received the same error.

[image]

As per the error, you are receiving this because the USE Database Statement is not supported in Azure synapse. Alternatively, you can connect to your database by directly opting from the drop down as mentioned below from your dedicated pool.

[image]